# What is returned by calling 'where'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following question, let

```
 @post=Post.where(title: "title1")
```

what should be `@post` if "title1" exists or not? How can I check if 'where' returned any element?

In my application I just called

```
  if(@post) .... else .... end
```

but it always get into else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@post=Post.where(title: "title1").first
```

Then `@post` would be either a `Post` object with `title = "title1"` or `nil`.

[.where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns a ActiveRecord_Relation object, which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments.

An alternative is to use [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) as suggested by @D-side in the comments:

```
@post = Post.find_by(title: "title1")
```

Comment: Alternative: `find_by`, takes the same as `where`, returns first occurrence or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @D-side; did not know that. I included it in the answer.